# Which compiler to use when learning D?

Tags: d, dmd, ldc

I'm interested in learning D. However I'm a bit turned of by the DMD, because it is not fully opensource. This is why I am considering using the LDC, but I'm not sure what's it's status. In the debian package it says:

```
Version: 1:0.14.0.dfsg-1     
LDC already compiles a lot of D code, but should still be considered beta quality. Take a look at the
     tickets to get a better impression on what still needs to be implemented.
```

I know Debian repositories can sometimes be a bit ancient, but 1.0.0 seems to be the latest LDC release.

I intend do use libraries written in C a lot. Which compiler will fit this purpose better? LDC or DMD? I know this question has been asked before, but all the questions I found are rather old and I want to know the current status.

Comment: on Linux they all work with C just as fine. I personally use dmd so a benefit there is you might have an easier time finding info or help with it but there's not that much of a difference between them all.

Comment: DMD **is** fully open-source! Saying it isn't is a lie! However, what you perhaps wanted to say is that you do not like that some parts of the DMD are released under a restrictive license. - Why do you care? You as DMD user are not restricted in any way!

Comment: We might disagree about the word. With open source I mean that it has an open source license. That I can change it at will and don't have to license it from Symantec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm interested in learning D. However I'm a bit turned of by the DMD, because it is not fully opensource.

**edit**: since April 8th 2017 DMD is [fully OpenSource](https://github.com/dlang/dmd/pull/6680).

---

<strike>This is just a licensing about the backend.</strike> The entire development happens on Github: https://github.com/dlang/dmd

My recommendation is to use DMD as it has the fastest compile-time which is quite helpful when learning a language (seriously it's blazingly fast!). On Linux you can easily install DMD - even just as a user - with the [install script](https://dlang.org/install.html):

```
curl https://dlang.org/install.sh | bash -s dmd
```

(see the [downloads page](http://dlang.org/download.html) for more instructions and download options.)

Last but not least there are a couple of nice tools like [`rdmd`](https://dlang.org/rdmd.html) (it allows a script-like execution of DMD source files) that you should familiarize yourself with, because they can save you a lot of time & make programming in D even more fun!

> This is why I am considering using the LDC, but I'm not sure what's it's status. In the debian package it says:
>   I know Debian repositories can sometimes be a bit ancient, but 1.0.0 seems to be the latest LDC release.

"A bit ancient" is an understatement ;-)
In case you want to go with LDC, you should definitively grab a [more recent release](https://github.com/ldc-developers/ldc/releases). As of now 1.0.0 is the latest release, but 1.1.0 will be released very soon (the second beta is already out). You can also grab the latest LDC with the install script:

```
curl https://dlang.org/install.sh | bash -s ldc
```

Comment: As an amendment to @greenify's answer, you may find DUB helpful. DUB offers an additional layer over the DMD compiler that automates packaging. I find double invaluable developing in D. For example, I can simply issue a command, `dub init foo`, to create a new D project from a template called `foo`. From inside `/foo`, I simply call `dub` to compile and run `foo`. I know your question is specifically about compiler choice, but I think this is a low cost solution in the domain of build environment that is a promising time saver. Find a link to the project here: https://github.com/dlang/dub.

Comment: `curl -fsS https://dlang.org/install.sh | bash -s ldc`  can be used to install LDC.